# Executing svn info in cronjob fails agianst remote server

Tags: svn, cron, centos

I have a script I am migrating from one server to another.  On the previous one it worked fine, but now a call to `svn info` is failing when run inside a cronjob.  The same call works fine if I `su` as the same user `cron` uses.  The call only fails when it is a `http://` url; info calls to `file:///` urls work perfectly.

This is a vanilla CentOS 6.5 server with minimal software installed (`svn 1.6.11`)

```
#cron 
*/1  *  *  *  * myuser /opt/update-stuff.sh >> /opt/update-stuff.log
#/1 is for testing this right now... got tired of waiting
```

The script looks a little like this, but a lot longer.  It is only the one call that is failing

```
# update-stuff.sh
# this call just outputs blank.  I can't tell what is failing 
echo ==[ remote test ]==
svn info http://svn.corp.com/svn/repo1

# this call works just fine.  not an auth test, just to show svn is working
echo ==[ local test ]==
svn info file:///opt/mirrors/repo1
```

Notes:

- If I `su` as `myuser` and run the script, everything is fine
- Path for `root` and `myuser` is the same (exactly)
- I simplified the script to just those two lines, and still get the same
- Verified the same `svn` binary is used
- Verified cron is actually running as that user :D

Failing all else, is there some way to look at `stderr` or some other output to hopefully see at least a simple error message.

**Additional Info:**

Thanks @LazyBadger.  Just seeing the error finally let me to this:

- Cron is not setting up the user's environment.
- It appears (though I am no expert) that `/etc/bashrc` and others are not run

**Solution:**

After finally getting the errors, I tried forcing svn to use the u/p.  This works, but it complains about saving the auth info.  So I edit `.subversion/servers`.  Still complains.  So add a `set` to the script.  See the environment variables aren't being set (wrong home).  To google! Then to a web-scraper that stole [the answer that helped me from serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/253522/cron-job-script-the-script-does-not-work-from-the-cron-or-it-does-not-start)

```
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed

# use root user, and 'su' to get the same environment as if the user logged in
*/5  *  *  *  * root su - myuser /opt/update-stuff.sh >> /opt/update-stuff.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unrelated**

- `*/1` in cron is **Bad Idea (tm)**
- In order to detect new commits into remote repo, you can use more lightweight and easier parsable svn commands, than `svn info`
- Successful operation with `file:///` protocol means nothing: file-based access doesn't use any authentication|authorization methods and (or) SVN-specific ACLs, which *can* (in theory) prevent accessing http-repo

**Related**

- In order to see all output in log, redirect stderr of `svn info` additionally, something like `svn info http://svn.corp.com/svn/repo1 >> /opt/update-remote.log 2>&1`
- Just idea. Under "some conditions" you may have connection timeout longer than 1 minute, and `*/1` preventing from from getting any response from remote side
- Around your 1-st note. Can't recall differences in environments for cron-job executed under some user and the same user in shell, but they *may* exist

Comment: On the unrelated... i know, that's for testing so I don't have to wait 5 minutes (for the active repos).  not sure a more lightweight way to check remote changes (interested)... and I know file:/// isn't related, it was just to show that `svn` worked inside the cron job.  Related: I will change the redirect and respond.  Connection timeouts do happen (but super rare, usually < 1 second response)

Comment: @AndrewBacker - lightweight *ideas* : `svn ls -v URL | head -n 1 |...` or `svn log -q URL | grep "|" | gawk {print $1}`. More usable way - using push instead of pull, i.e on repo-side in post-commit hook <do something> in order to notify about commit

Comment: I don't see how `svn log` is more lightweight.  `svn ls` may work, but it seems about the same effort (or more?) than a simple `info`.  For pushes, thats a no-go.  It took me a good two years to get them to finally add a comment-length check to the commits.

Comment: And yep, you are right, `2>&1` gives me the error (auth error).  Not sure why it tries to use the login username rather than the cached credentials when run as cron (on this box!).